# SphericalPlot3D moving a sphere's center

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I can't seem to graph `x^2 + y^2 + (z - 3)^2 = 9` in `SphericalPlot3D`, because all I can set is the radius being equal to 3, but can't compensate for the `z - 3` part. How do I move my sphere up the z axis 3!!

Comment: It is easy with `ContourPlot3D`: `ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + (z - 3)^2 == 9, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 6}]`

Answer (score 3):

Write the equation for the sphere in spherical coordinates and solve for $r$

```
ClearAll[r, θ, ϕ]
eqn = r^2 Sin[θ]^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 + 
      r^2 Sin[θ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
       (r Cos[θ] - 3)^2 == 9;

r = r /. Last@Solve[eqn, r]

(*   6 Cos[θ]   *)
```

Plot the result

```
SphericalPlot3D[r, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]
```

[image]